# Categorical variable with multiple labels

Tags: regression, classification, feature-selection, categorical-encoding

I have a silly question - I have in model several variables with 100+ possible labels each (like Country that stores country code, Industry storing industry code, etc.) - I have to somehow convert this to a data consumed by a classifier.

I could encode these variables with OHE and have over 400 new variables, but then I have another issue - some of labels in these variables need to stay (so some of newly created variables will stay whatever their statistical importance is) and I cannot drop them, therefore I won't be able to reduce the number of variables from 400 to 50, but rather to 380 and I have a pretty small data set.

How would You guys approach it? Does it even make sense to encode it? I had a thought on that to replace these labels with some unified dict labels like country -> country risk with labels low, medium, high, but that one is not simple as well, but for "political" reasons this will not go through.

Comment: Please explain OHE!

Comment: One Hot Encoder to encode categorical variables

Answer (score 0):

Leave one out variety of mean target encoding comes to mind (with high cardinality, target leakage is a serious concern, so other varieties might be unsuitable).
There's a nice flowchart for encoding method selection at https://innovation.alteryx.com/encode-smarter/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look up [entity embedding](https://towardsdatascience.com/entity-embeddings-for-ml-2387eb68e49),or general approaches other than one-hot encoding, [like this](https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159). If you are willing to further go out of your way, I suggest you look up [Spectral encoding](https://towardsdatascience.com/spectral-encoding-of-categorical-features-b4faebdf4a).